# jq to update key:value objects with matching strings at the begining

Tags: json, string, bash, jq

I need to update below json file values where key matches a substring.
sample.json

```
{
"A": "a"
"re": {
  "jok/pok": ^20.0,
  "sok/dok": ^23.0,
  "jok/ssd": ^32.0
}
}
```

now I need to append `-dev` to those key/values where key starts with `jok`.

```
{
"A": "a"
"re": {
  "jok/pok": ^20.0-dev,
  "sok/dok": ^23.0,
  "jok/ssd": ^32.0-dev
}
}
```

I know I'm missing some really simple solution.

Comment: What you have isn't a valid JSON. The values need to be quoted as strings to be called valid

Comment: Please show us your attempt!

Comment: If your input really is invalid JSON but like the example shown, then you could use a tool such as [tag:hjson] to fix it.  From there, the jq solution is indeed simple, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is actually well-formed and valid JSON:

```json
{
  "A": "a",
  "re": {
    "jok/pok": "^20.0",
    "sok/dok": "^23.0",
    "jok/ssd": "^32.0"
  }
}
```

The following jq program generates the output as required:

```
.re |= with_entries(select(.key|startswith("jok")).value |= . + "-dev")
```

Output:

```json
{
  "A": "a",
  "re": {
    "jok/pok": "^20.0-dev",
    "sok/dok": "^23.0",
    "jok/ssd": "^32.0-dev"
  }
}
```